# Android invalidateOptionsMenu not updating Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm targeting Android >=4 and I have an issue with the ActionBar.

I need to dynamically update the action bar and all the code seems to work fine on a Nexus 7 and Nexus 4.  The problem I have is with an Xperia S (Android 4.1.2).  The Nexus devices update the ActionBar immediately.  The Xperia only updates when the hardware menu button is pressed.

I call invalidateOptionsMenu() which in turn successfully calls the onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) on all devices.  The difference is that the Xperia is simply not updating the display.  As soon as I click the hardware menu button, up pops the menu items and buttons.

I've read quite a few posts and tried numerous methods - I simply can't get the Xperia to behave properly.

Comment: I have the same problem with the ActionBarSherlock library. It works fine on API >= 4.2 but not on on 4.0 <= API < 4.2 devices that I tried. Still no solution so I had to add checks to visible buttons that were not supposed to be visible while I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've messed around with this and the best I can come up with is to recreate the activity which gives and unacceptable user experience.

Everything works fine on devices with soft menu buttons.  Until I can come up with something better I've decided to force all menu items on to the action bar drop down menu for devices with a hardware menu button.

I detect the hardware menu button in the onCreate of the Activity;

```
this.hardwareMenuButton = ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext()).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

Then I have something like this;

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add("Refresh");        
    if(this.hardwareButton) {
        menuItem.setShowAsActionFlags(android.view.MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
    } else {
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh);
        menuItem.setShowAsActionFlags(android.view.MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```